# Civi webform - contacts prefilled based on relationship are duplicated

Tags: webform-civicrm

Civi 4.4.6, Drupal 7.37, Civi Webform 7.x-4.10

I have a webform that should be prepopulating several contacts with the same relationship type (e.g., Employee 1, Employee 2).  However, Employee 1 is prefilled in each of the contact sections, and if different information is entered in the Employee 2 box, it overwrites Employee 1's contact record.  I've done this successfully on other sites so I'm not sure if I've missed a setting (duplicate is definitely UNchecked) or if this is a bug in this version of the webform integration module?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Hey Lesley - are you really on CiviCRM 4.4.6 - or is that a typo?

Comment: That is not a typo.

Comment: were the other sites you were successful on also 4.4.6?

Comment: Unfortunately - or fortunately, depending on your definition - this is the only 4.4.x site I work with that has Civi webform, so I have no basis of apples-to-apples comparison.  It sounds like I may need to bag the hope of prefilling the info, which is a bit of a disappointment, but until I can get them to commit to upgrading this may be the best we can do for now.